# What is controlling the precision when writing reals in postgres copy command?

Tags: postgresql

I do the following copy command from psql:

```
copy yy_caa_epdall to '/tmp/CAAImport-1234567' delimiter '|' csv header;
```

and get a file with lines like the following:

```
    1011192|1|1.2|0.34|44.8|0.3|57.4|0.31|19.3|41.7|0.23|7.9|0.2|4.9|0.19||||||||||-0.031|0.22|0.02|0.12|0.27|0.14|5.278|0.17|8.605|0.064|||-0.24||-0.11|0.16|1.8|0.26||
```

When I issue the same command through jdbc within a scala program the same row looks like this:

```
1011192|1|-1.20000005|0.340000004|44.7999992|0.300000012|57.4000015|0.310000002|19.2999992|41.6999969|0.230000004|7.9000001|0.200000003|4.9000001|0.189999998||||||||||-0.0309999995|0.219999999|0.0199999996|0.119999997|0.270000011|0.140000001|5.27799988|0.170000002|8.60499954|0.064000003|||-0.239999995||-0.109999999|0.159999996|1.79999995|0.25999999||
```

This is under Mac 10.10.2.  I would normally suspect an environment variable but nothing was immediately obvious.

Comment: How that line is actually stored in the database and what is the datatype of those fields?

Comment: All numerical fields are real and there are 4 text fields.